# Post to Facebook not working from delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

I have added FBSdk in my project along with SBJson classes, what files should i import in my second view controller to work my code ?

I want to post on Fb using the description under url so for that i need to include this code into my second view controller, but i am stuck in a part i founded that the below code should be added in the second view controller but the "delegate:self" not works, as i am doing this first time so can any one guide me how should i code in my second view controller keeping into account the values from the app delegate (How should i get the values from the app delegate of FB to the second view so that i can add this code in second code plz can any one correct this code)

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"YOUR_APP_ID"];
```

**// how should i take this id from the app delegate ?**

```
 NSArray* permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream", 
 @"publish_stream", nil];
[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];

   NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] 
initWithCapacity:1]
 [params setObject:@"Testing" forKey:@"name"];
  [params setObject:@"IMAGE_URL" forKey:@"picture"];
   [params setObject:@"Description" forKey:@"description"];
  [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" 
    andParams:params 
  andHttpMethod:@"POST" 
   andDelegate:self];
```

Is the above code correct ? 
How should i implement it in my second view controller in -(void)fb_share (method).

My App Delegate File is Like this :

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ServerRequests.h"
#import "DBManager.h"
#import "SBJson.h"


#include "FBSession.h"
#import "FBRequest.h"
#import "FBGraphUser.h"


NSString *const FBSessionStateChangedNotification = @"com.myapp:FBSessionStateChangedNotification";

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize userId;
@synthesize dbSnyced;
@synthesize fbId;
@synthesize loginView;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_viewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}




 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   self.fbId = @"-1";
    self.dbSnyced = NO;
    self.loginView = nil;

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    

    if (![self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO]) {

        [self showLogin:NO];
    }

    return YES;
}



- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

    [self checkAccountLogin];
}

- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self hideLogin:NO];
}

- (void)  applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationWillTerminate");
    [self hideLogin:NO];
    [FBSession.activeSession close];
}

- (void) checkAccountLogin
{
    self.dbSnyced = NO;
    if([ServerRequests serverIsReachableAlertIfNo:YES]) {

        DBManager *db = [[[DBManager alloc] initWithPath:DB_NAME] autorelease];
        NSDictionary *userDic = [[db smartQueryForArrayWithStatement:@"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1"] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *loginType = [userDic objectForKey:@"login_type"];
        if([loginType isEqualToString:@"none"]) {
            NSLog(@"no login type");
            [self showLogin:NO];
        }
        else {
            self.userId = [[userDic objectForKey:@"user_id"] intValue];
            if([loginType isEqualToString:@"Facebook"]) {
                NSLog(@"Facebook account");

                [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
            }
            else if([loginType isEqualToString:@"MyApp"]) {
                NSLog(@"MyApp account");
            }
        }
    }
}


#pragma - Fb stuff

/*
 * Callback for session changes.
 */
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"sessionStateChanged");
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            if (!error) {
                [self handleFbUserDetails];
            }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification object:session];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        if(self.loginView) {
            [self.loginView hideLoading];
        }


    }
}

/*
 * Opens a Facebook session and optionally shows the login UX.
 */
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState state,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                                             [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                 state:state
                                                                 error:error];
                                         }];
}


/*
 * If we have a valid session at the time of openURL call, we handle
 * Facebook transitions by passing the url argument to handleOpenURL
 */
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (BOOL) activeFBSession
{
    return FBSession.activeSession.isOpen;
}

- (void) closeFBSession
{
    NSLog(@"closeFBSession");
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}


- (void) showLogin:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(!self.loginView) {
        self.loginView = [[[LoginViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        [[self.navigationController topViewController] presentViewController:self.loginView animated:animated completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void) hideLogin:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(self.loginView) {
        [self.viewController gotToTab:0];
        [self.loginView hideLoading];
        [[self.navigationController topViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:animated completion:^{
            self.loginView = nil;
            NSLog(@"self.loginView = nil");
        }];
    }
}


- (void) handleFbUserDetails
{
    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"fb connected");

             self.fbId = [user objectForKey:@"id"];
             self.userId = -1;             

             ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ServerRequests ASIFormDataRequestForSrcipt:@"facebookUser"];
             [request setPostValue:[user objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"fbId"];
             [request setPostValue:user.first_name forKey:@"first_name"];
             [request setPostValue:user.last_name forKey:@"last_name"];
            [request setPostValue:user.location.name forKey:@"location"];
             [request setCompletionBlock:^{
                 NSString *response = [request responseString];
                 NSLog(@"facebookUser response: %@", response);
                 if([response rangeOfString:@"ERROR"].location == NSNotFound) {
                     self.userId = [response intValue];

                     DBManager *db = [[DBManager alloc] initWithPath:DB_NAME];
                     NSString *q = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE table SET login_type = 'Facebook', user_id = '%@' WHERE id = 1", response];
                     NSLog(@"%@", q);
                     [db executeStatement:q];
                     [db release];                     
                 }
                 else {                     

                 }
                 [self sessionBecameActive];
             }];
             [request startAsynchronous];
             [self hideLogin:YES];
         }
         else {
             NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook Request Error" message:@"Cannot connect to Facebook." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

             alert.delegate = self;
             [alert show];
             [alert release];
             if(self.loginView) {
                 [self.loginView hideLoading];
             }
         }
         [ServerRequests SyncDataBase];
     }];
}

- (void) signOut
{
    [self closeFBSession];
    DBManager *db = [[DBManager alloc] initWithPath:DB_NAME];
    [db executeStatement:@"UPDATE table SET login_type = 'none' WHERE id = 1"];
    [db release];
    [self showLogin:YES];
}

- (void) sessionBecameActive
{
    [self.viewController sessionBecameActive];
}

@end
```

Can any one figure out what code should i write in the -(void)fb_share method in second view controller by getting values from the delegate ?
Any Help !

---

I did this ... and getting Error: HTTP status code: 400 ... but the user name get's displayed on alert

```
     [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
    ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

       //     NSArray* permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream",
          //                           @"publish_stream", nil];
           // [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];


          self.params =  [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
             @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
             @"https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
            @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
            @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
            @"The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", @"description",
             nil];

            UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"Upload to FB?"
                                message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Upload to ""%@"" Account?", user.name]
                                delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                otherButtonTitles:@"No",@"Yes", nil];

            [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                                          parameters:self.params
                                          HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                   completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                       if (!error) {
                                           UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                                               initWithTitle:@"Success"
                                                               message:@"PostUploaded"
                                                               delegate:self
                                                               cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                               otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

                                           [tmp show];
                                           [tmp release];
                                       }
                                   }];

            [tmp show];
            [tmp release];

                   }
    }];
```

.. what should i do now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare `facebook` as a `property in .h` file of your `appDelegate`

then in `second view controller` import `AppDelegate`

in .m file where you want the Facebook object

get it like

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
Facebook *facebook = appDelegate.facebook;
```

Comment: your code did not worked ..but then i tried this   [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
        parameters:params
                                              HTTPMethod:@"POST"
completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {  if (!error) { UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Post Uploaded"  delegate:self  cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil]; [tmp show]; [tmp release];} }];but its giving me out error Error: HTTP status code: 400 can you tell me what does that mean ?